# DataTables not getting populated on Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have been trying to a table to get populated by using data from a ajax request. I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/object_data.html) as the starting point.

I have created a PHP web service that when queried:

```
table_ws.php?id=2
```

Returns the data in the following format:

```
{"status":200,"status_message":"Yahoo!","data":[{"sent_date":"2012-01-01","serial_number":"342312","text":"Great service","looked_into":"0"},{"sent_date":"2012-02-16","serial_number":"2343662","text":"Happy with the product","looked_into":"0"},{"sent_date":"2012-03-04","serial_number":"342356","text":"Experience could have been better","looked_into":"0"}]}
```

I have created the table in HTML like so:

```
 <table id="tbl_details" class="tbl">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Sent Date</th>
                            <th>Number</th>
                            <th>Text</th>
                            <th>Resolved?</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
    </table>
```

The relevant parts of my javascript are as follows (for the sake of clarity I am excluding the code not relevant for the question):

```
...
...
...
 .on("click", function(d) {  
                table.ajax="table_ws.php?id=" + d.id 
                table.columns=[
                                {"data": "sent_date"},
                                {"data": "serial_number"},
                                {"data": "text"},
                                {"data": "looked_into"}
                            ]; 
                            });
...
...
...
$(document).ready( function () {
                table=$('#tbl_details').DataTable();
                table.processing=true;
                table.serverSide=true;          
            });
```

Though the table appears as expected on the page, it is not populated "onclick" of the button.

[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796393/populate-datatable-with-ajax-call) on StackOverflow says that the table needs to be destroyed and recreated everytime new data is put in. But the function fnDestroy() does not seem to exist.

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: What error are you getting when you are trying to destroy the table  **fnDestroy()** ??

Comment: The error is: table.fnDestroy is not a function

Comment: The table exists. I can do alerts to print table.processing and table.ajax to get the corresponding values.